# Trying to set up a Save/Load system, need help loading in values from a class to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm saving and loading values from a specific class. I'm calling out the class that holds the values and using them. But for some reason when the values are loaded in the class that holds the values, the class that calls out the class with values doesn't get those values. How can resolve this?

Checked if values are loaded in, they are(shown in SaveSystem class)
Checked if values are received in the Shop class, they aren't(shown)

```
public class AllData {
    public double bucketProg;
    public double milk;
    public double totalMilk;
    public double milkPrice;
    public double totalClicks;
    public double coins;
    public double totalCoins;
    public double upgradeBucketCost = 10;
    public double qualityMilkCost = 1000;
    public double BucketLevel = 1;
    public double milkLevel = 1;
    public double multiplier = 1;
}

public class SaveSystem {
    AllData allData = new AllData();
    public void Save(AllData allData) {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", FileMode.Create);
        bf.Serialize(file, allData);
        file.Close();
    }
    public void Load() {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey")) {

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", FileMode.Open);
            allData = (AllData) bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            //here I made sure to check if the data is being loaded, which it did
            Debug.Log(allData.milk);

        }

    }

}

public class Shop: MonoBehaviour {
    AllData allData = new AllData();
    private SaveSystem saveSystem = new SaveSystem();

    public Text milkText;

    public void Start() {
        saveSystem.Load();
    }

    public void Update() { 
        //output is 0
        milkText.text = allData.milk;
        saveSystem.Save(this.allData);
    }

}
```

Comment: `SaveSystem.Load` is marked as void so the data object created there just disappears when it completes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problems is you forgetting to mark `AllData` as `System.Serializable`;
Also, making the `Load` function return the `AllData` that was loaded.

After some modifications, I tested it on my end and it seems to work.
(Tested it on `Unity 2019.1.12f1`)

**This was the code that I used to test**:

#### Shop.cs

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour {
    AllData allData = new AllData();
    private SaveSystem saveSystem = new SaveSystem();

    public Text milkText;

    public void Start() {
        // assigns '-1' if data was not found;
        var loadedData = saveSystem.Load();
        allData.milk = (int) (loadedData == null ? -1 : loadedData.milk);

        milkText.text = allData.milk.ToString();
    }

    public void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K)){
            TestSaving();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J)) {
            TestAddingMilkValue();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I)) {
            TestLoadingMilkValue();
        }

        #region Local_Function
        void TestSaving() {
            Debug.Log("SAVING...");
            saveSystem.Save(this.allData);
        }

        void TestAddingMilkValue() {
            Debug.Log("ADD...");
            ++allData.milk;
            milkText.text = allData.milk.ToString();
        }

        void TestLoadingMilkValue() {
            Debug.Log("LOADING...");
            var loadedData = saveSystem.Load();
            allData.milk = (int)(loadedData == null ? -1 : loadedData.milk);

            milkText.text = allData.milk.ToString();
        }
        #endregion
    }

}
```

#### SaveSystem.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AllData {
    public double bucketProg = 0;
    public double milk = 0;
    public double totalMilk = 0;
    public double milkPrice = 0;
    public double totalClicks = 0;
    public double coins = 0;
    public double totalCoins = 0;
    public double upgradeBucketCost = 10;
    public double qualityMilkCost = 1000;
    public double BucketLevel = 1;
    public double milkLevel = 1;
    public double multiplier = 1;
}

public class SaveSystem {
    AllData allData = new AllData();
    public void Save(AllData allData) {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", FileMode.Create);
        bf.Serialize(file, allData);
        file.Close();
    }
    public AllData Load() {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey")) {

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", FileMode.Open);
            allData = (AllData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            return allData;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

(^ Might want to separate `AllData` into a different source file.)

Though it is just my personal preference, but you can refactor `Load` into this too:

```
// Returns true if the data exists; False if the data did not.
public bool TryLoad(out AllData allData) {
    allData = null;
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey")) {

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/allData.hey", FileMode.Open);
        allData = (AllData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
    return allData != null;
}
```

This way, you don't have to manually check if `AllData` is null whenever you fetch it, as the function "auto-checks" for you.